# How to fix Datatype error float and str in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

in pandas DataFrame I want to create a conditional column. new column flag would be 1 if a is greater than b else 0

I am using below but getting TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

```
df['flag'] =  df['a'] >  df['b'], 1, 0
```

How can I resolve this error?

| A | b | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24.43048 | 22 | 1 |
| 29.0 |  | 0 |
|  | 0 | 0 |
| 70.2323 | 70 | 1 |
| 39.0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 |  | 0 |

Comment: A sample of your DataFrame with a few representative rows would be very helpful. It almost seems like you're missing `np.where`. `df['flag'] =  np.where(df['a'] >  df['b'], 1, 0)` but this wouldn't fix the comparison issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d)).replace(np.nan,'').astype(str)
df
df.dtypes
```

Output:

[image]

Calculate Flag:

```
for i,x in df.iterrows():
    try:
        df.loc[i,'Flag'] = 1 if float(x[0]) > float(x[1]) else 0
    except ValueError:
        df.loc[i,'Flag'] = 0
df
df.dtypes
```

[image]